# Returning Result type in Rust

Tags: rust, return

I'm very new to Rust, since I decided to jump directly from Python to challenge myself.
I couldn't figure out the Result return type, so I thought maybe here I would find some help.

I'm currently writing a program which implements an input(message) function, like so:

```
fn input(message: &str) -> io::Result<String> {
    print!("{}", message);
    io::stdout().flush()?;

    let mut user_input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input)?;

    Ok(user_input.trim().to_owned())
}
```

(From a tutorial). The code works fine, but I'm trying to figure out how I could use `std::result::Result` instead of `io::Result`, just because.

I tried converting it to:

```
fn input(message: &str) -> Result<String, Error> {
/*  */
}
```

But the compiler let me know that the question mark operator can't convert its error into `std::fmt::Error`.
I'm just trying to figure out how to use Result correctly as a return type.
Should I specify an Err(something) return? In that case, I wouldn't even know how to do that.

I'm in need of a clear explanation of what the hell is going on (like, veeery clear so my monkey brain can comprehend stuff). Thanks in advance, people.

Comment: It depends on what `Error` is, but it sounds like you simply imported the wrong one. `std::io::Result<T>` is an alias for `Result<T, std::io::Error>`. So you would need to import `std::io::Error` instead of `std::fmt::Error`; they are different types.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't know it was an alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine Errors in your custom ErrorType:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyCustomError {
    ParseError(ParseIntError),
    IoError(std::io::Error),
}

impl std::error::Error for MyCustomError {}

impl fmt::Display for MyCustomError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            MyCustomError::ParseError(e) => write!(f, "Parse Error {e}"),
            MyCustomError::IoError(e) => write!(f, "Io Error {e}"),
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use dyn errors (read more in rustbook):

```
fn throw_dyn_error() -> Result<(), Box<dyn error::Error>> {
    //...
    Err("What happens".into())
}
```

In other *production-ready* way you can use
[anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) crate and [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror/) crate

Comment: I think the easiest and most me-friendly way is to use the extern crates you provided. Thanks for the answer!